# Ruby on Rails -- validating a unique record, not just unique attributes of a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, validates-uniqueness-of

This might be a very question, but I'm trying to allow only unique records for a table called "Favorites" with attributes "lightbulb_id" and "student_id." I know about model validations

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_name
end
```

But, I want to validate the uniqueness of the entire record (so the combination of `lightbulb_id` and `student_id`). So, `lightbulb_id` and `student_id` can be duplicated (a student can "favorite" multiple lightbulb_id's) and consequently the same student_id can appear multiple times in the Favorites table with different lightbulb_ids. But the specific combination shouldn't be duplicated (a student cannot favorite a lightbulb twice)

This might be a very basic question, any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following validation rule:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :student_id, scope: [:lightbulb_id]
```

Comment: validates :lightbulb_id, uniqueness: { scope: :student_id }

I tried this and added a unique index on my Favorites table and it seems to be working. I'm not entirely sure how the scope specification works though. Does it check for uniqueness of the student_id and attribute specified in scope combined?